# 'no such name' error on all gem install attempts

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just installed Ruby 2.2.2 on a Windows 7 64-bit VM. Every `gem install <gemname>` attempt fails with the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem '<gemname>' ()= 0), here is why:
> Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name
> (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
> ```

However, the list generated by the `gem list` contains the gem that I thought failed. Is it actually installed or not? I assume it isn't but even if it is, the error concerns me.

I know that I am working behind a proxy so I've tried appending `--http-proxy` but that hasn't helped either.

Any ideas to troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Comment: I had every single gem install failing, even `gem update --system`. I think my router did something retarded. Rebooted everything and problem was "resolved".

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that one of the gems that you installed declares an invalid dependency such as `<gemname>` (specifically).

To validate this, open an `irb` or `pry` console and run `Gem.loaded_specs` to see if the string `<gemname>` shows up anywhere.

You could also try updating your rubygems with `gem update --system`.

And finally, you could also try to run `gem check` to validate all installed gems.

Unfortunately, this appears to be an issue that needs to be investigated to get to the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue before figuring out my session was fucked up. Indeed the command `whoami` was displaying an id and not my username. I logged out and logged in again and everything was solved.